# How do I create a report with subtotals and a grand total in Power BI?

Tags: report, business-intelligence, subtotal, powerbi

Currently, I'm using the Power BI Designer (newest version). I'm completely new to it. I'm wondering how to get the subtotal of a group of items and then get the report grand total. I only need the subtotal for one column (ie. price). The grouping will be on 3 columns (date, location, itemname).

Power BI is connected to a Azure SQL database (not SSAS).

Answer (score 4):

Update: Matrix is now supported in both Power BI Desktop and PowerBI.com.

Just add the 3 levels of grouping and the measure you want. The subtotals will show no problem.

Answer (score 3):

As *Lukasz* suggesting, You can use **Matrix visual** in Power BI for achieving this requirement.

[image]

Find the option to enable/disable ***Sub-Total*** and ***Grant Total*** option in **Format tab** of the matrix visual.

[image]

Sample Matrix visual,

- **Red** color highlighted Total is **Sub-Total**.
- **Blue** color highlighted Total is **Grant-Total**.
- **Green** color highlighted as hierarchy option for Matrix visual.

[image]

Some of the Matrix visual features are explained below,

- To expand the next level of the hierarchy, you have to click the hierarchy icon
  available in the top right corner of the visual [image]   (*you can see by hovering mouse into Matrix visual*).
- [image]**Drill Up** – drill upper level after you drilled down Click to turn on
- [image]**Drill down** – Turn on Drill down for drilling specific hierarchy
- [image]**Go to next level in the hierarchy** – Parallel hierarchy drill down
- [image]**Expand all down one level in the hierarchy** – Level by level hierarchy
  drilling